# Simulator won't start with iphone X skin

Tags: codenameone

I run the chart demo of codename one in the simulator with netbean 12.6 on windows 10.
It shows error messages.

Retina Scale: 1.0
Failed loading the skin file: /iPhoneX.skin
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.initializeCoordinates(JavaSEPort.java:2374)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.loadSkinFile(JavaSEPort.java:2595)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.loadSkinFile(JavaSEPort.java:4574)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.init(JavaSEPort.java:4786)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.initImpl(CodenameOneImplementation.java:17

The simulator won't start. I have tried to uninstall Netbeans, codename one plug-in. But it didn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using ant or maven?
Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

We released a fix for this yesterday and located the issue. It was caused due to a problem in the CI scripts that pushed out a bad update of the jar. We didn't notice it in manual testing since we had a downloaded skin selected on that machine.

Steve has added some tests to the CI to address this.