# Simulator can't load iPhoneX.skin

Tags: codenameone

I use Codename One plugin 6.0 with eclipse 2021-12 on a Windows 10 Laptop.
I switched between two skins. Next time I tried to start the simulator it don't work.

```
Adding CEF to classpath
Retina Scale: 1.0
Failed loading the skin file: /iPhoneX.skin
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.initializeCoordinates(JavaSEPort.java:2374)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.loadSkinFile(JavaSEPort.java:2595)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.loadSkinFile(JavaSEPort.java:4574)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.init(JavaSEPort.java:4786)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.init(JavaCEFSEPort.java:67)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.initImpl(CodenameOneImplementation.java:178)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.init(Display.java:530)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$4.run(Executor.java:282)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Hotswap Agent not detected. To enable enhanced live class reloading feature, run with DCEVM JDK and add -XX:HotswapAgent=core to the VM options
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1349)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1324)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1353)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$C.blit(JavaSEPort.java:1496)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.flushGraphics(JavaSEPort.java:5812)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$C$3.run(JavaSEPort.java:1661)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1368)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1155)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$C.drawScreenBuffer(JavaSEPort.java:1571)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$C.access$700(JavaSEPort.java:1293)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$C$1.run(JavaSEPort.java:1462)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Rendering frame took too long 217 milliseconds
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1349)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1324)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1353)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$C.blit(JavaSEPort.java:1496)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$C.blit(JavaSEPort.java:1504)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.flushGraphics(JavaSEPort.java:5801)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.paintDirty(CodenameOneImplementation.java:644)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.paintDirty(JavaSEPort.java:2351)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1289)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1192)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$C.drawScreenBuffer(JavaSEPort.java:1571)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$C.access$700(JavaSEPort.java:1293)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$C$1.run(JavaSEPort.java:1462)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

From what I' ve read so far, the iPhoneX.skin should be generated from the javaSE.jar but I can't find the .skin file on my machine so maybe that is the problem?

Comment: This was fixed yesterday. Please update your project or ideally migrate to maven. You can read this for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70313319/simulator-wont-start-with-iphone-x-skin/70329313

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!